# How to override getAvailableMethods method in Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList

Tags: magento2, overrides

anyone have idea how to override `getAvailableMethods` method from

`Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList` class.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is the best way to override a public function at magento2. So my suggestion is that use Plugin on this case.

As we know that Using `after, before` plugin methods, we can change the after changes parameter, return value of the  original `getAvailableMethods()`

But if you want to  **full changes return of this function then use around methods** `aroundGetAvailableMethods()` this method is **capable to changes original function output/return**

### An ideal around Plugin on this class:

```
<?php


namespace StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\Magento\Payment\Model;


class MethodListPlugin {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
     * @deprecated 100.1.3 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory
     * @deprecated 100.2.0 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $methodSpecificationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private $paymentMethodList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private $paymentMethodInstanceFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
     * @param Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory
    ) {
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->methodSpecificationFactory = $specificationFactory;
    }
    public function aroundGetAvailableMethods(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,    
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    )
    {
        /*
         * if want to origina function then use 
         *  return $proceed($quote);
         */

        $store = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;
        $availableMethods = [];

        foreach ($this->getPaymentMethodList()->getActiveList($store) as $method) {
            $methodInstance = $this->getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()->create($method);
            if ($methodInstance->isAvailable($quote) && $this->_canUseMethod($methodInstance, $quote)) {
                $methodInstance->setInfoInstance($quote->getPayment());
                $availableMethods[] = $methodInstance;
            }
        }
        /**
         * return of $availableMethod mean you have override 
         *  original function fully
         * 
         */
        return $availableMethods;        
    }
   /**
     * Check payment method model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface $method
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _canUseMethod($method, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote)
    {
        return $this->methodSpecificationFactory->create(
            [
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX,
            ]
        )->isApplicable(
            $method,
            $quote
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method list.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodList()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodList === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodList = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodList;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method instance factory.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `etc/di.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList" type="Company\Module\Model\Payment\MethodList" />
</config>
```

add file `MethodList.php` in `Company/Module/Model/Payment` location

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Company\Module\Model\Payment;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;

class MethodList extends \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList
{
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory
     */
    protected $methodSpecificationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private $paymentMethodList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private $paymentMethodInstanceFactory;
    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->methodSpecificationFactory = $specificationFactory;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *  Display payment methods according to the installer selected - MB
     * 
     */
    public function getAvailableMethods(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        // overriden method
    }
}
```